# Semantic UI progress bars change value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, semantic-ui

I have a couple of progress bars which I set up with Semantic UI and they work and I can also change the percentage value with jQuery.

```
<div class="ui teal progress" data-percent="" id="example0" style="width:200px;">
 <div class="bar"></div>
 </div>
```

Changing the percentage with jQuery:

```
$("#example0").progress({percent:30});
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to read the percentage from a text file and change it but it doesn't seem to work. This is the file I have (reading it isn't a problem it works on other occasions):

```
1;1;1;40;3.4;5;12;30;43;10;-

1;1;2;100;3.7;3;7;30;37;23;-
```

And I need something like this to read from it:

```
 $("#example0").progress({percent:'table[0][5]'});
```

(Where [0] accesses the first row of my text file and [5] the fourth element.)

If somebody knows the right way/syntax? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why is the array var in quotes? Try
`$("#example0").progress({percent: table[0][5]});`

Comment: @UjjwalArora Doesn't work even like this. Unfortunately!

Comment: Maybe the numbers in the file are being read as strings? Try converting it to an integer using `Integer.parseInt(table[0][5])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this

```
var table = []; // data from the files
var fileData = [
    "1;1;1;40;3.4;5;12;30;43;10;-",
    "1;1;2;100;3.7;3;7;30;37;23;-"
]; // read the data from a file and add each line to array

for(var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) { // for each file data
    table.push(fileData[i].split(";")); // split on the delimiter and push to the table array
}

$("#example0").progress({
  percent: Number(table[0][5]) // convert the value from the table to a number
}); // set percentage
```

I assume you already know how to read the data in, so I just showed the process to update the progress bar accordingly.

You can find a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/z10s2s6o/